# How do you handle changes to your resources?

Tags: http, rest, caching

I have a question, if somebody can give an pseudo example how is this handled, I would appreciate it.

Let's say that my application has urls that you can execute a GET against

```
/clients/{clientId}/contactsSummary
/locations/{locationId}/contactsSummary
```

and I want to do cashing. Now if I do POST/PATCH/DELETE on

```
/contacts/{contactId}
```

how does the cache get invalidated. Obviously, change, creation or deletion of the contact would cause first two urls to return cached version, which would be incorrect. What is the mechanism to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If the front end needs absolutely the most recent information, do not cache.  Otherwise, add an expiration time to every cached item, which could be from 1 second to 1 hour (or more) from the moment they are retrieved.

You could need to handle consistency issues, though.  For example, you could have a non-expired reference to an expired contact.

Assume `cache` is a dictionary from an URL to a tuple `(expires,data)`.  The pseudo-code to retrieve an URL would be:

```
cacheItem= cache[ULR]
if( cacheItem == null || cacheItem.expires < currentTime )
    cacheItem= ( currentTime + 1_hour , http_get(URL) )
    cache[ULR]= cacheItem
return cacheItem.data
```

Answer (score 0):

The client decides if he wants to retrieve the current representation of a resource. Use what is known as "conditional GET".

> The semantics of the GET method change to a "conditional GET" if the request message includes an If-Modified-Since, If-Unmodified-Since, If-Match, If-None-Match, or If-Range header field. A conditional GET method requests that the entity be transferred only under the circumstances described by the conditional header field(s). The conditional GET method is intended to reduce unnecessary network usage by allowing cached entities to be refreshed without requiring multiple requests or transferring data already held by the client.

(Section 9.3 of http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

How does this work? **C** is the client, **S** is the server.

**C**

```
GET /path/to/resource
```

**S**

```
200 OK
ETag: foo
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:00 GMT
```

**C**

The client `PUT`s a modified version.

```
PUT /path/to/resource
If-Match: foo
```

**S**

The client had the current version so a `PUT` on the resource is OK.

```
200 OK
ETag: bar
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:46:00 GMT
```

**C**

The client `PUT`s a modiefied version but in the meantime the resource has changed and the `ETag: bar` doesn't match any longer.

```
PUT /path/to/resource
If-Match: bar
```

**S**

```
412 Precondition Failed
```

**C**

The client `GET`s the current version of the resource.

```
GET /PATH/to/resource
```

**S**

```
200 OK
ETag: baz
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:47:00 GMT
```

**C**

Now the client can `PUT` the resource again.

```
PUT /path/to/resource
If-Match: ba7
```

**S**

```
200 OK
ETag: qux
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:48:00 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but that is not actually what I was asking. That makes sense when we are talking about one url, but in my example, the entity is being modified, but some of the attributes of that entity are used to create a resource on different url. Does that make sense?